# Run script after router-outlet finishes rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, facebook-comments, angular-router

I want to integrate facebook comments in my application.

I've placed

```
<div class="detailed__comments">
    <div class="fb-comments" [attr.data-href]="href" data-numposts="5"></div>
</div>
```

in my html file and this script

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=225580208017079&autoLogAppEvents=1';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }
```

in my `app.component.ts` in ngAfterViewInit(), however, in some cases script runs before html is rendered, and this html is rendered in `router-outlet` in `app.component.html` file. Is there any event to catch after `router-outlet` is finished rendering? Or another way to run the script after html.

P.S. In some cases script runs after html is rendered and comments are displayed nicely.

Comment: You could try using jquery and $(document).ready event

Comment: I have comments on many pages and want to avoid scripting all of them. Plus I don't want to use jquery with angular :p